# Arithmetically weighted sum of half of the combinatorial numbers

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I would like to see a proof for the identity
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom{2n}{n+k} = \frac{n}{2}\binom{2n}{n}$$ This was suggested by the OEIS sequence (https://oeis.org/A002457), but I haven't been able to prove it.

Comment: I think this should be moved to m.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$k=\dfrac{(n+k)-(n-k)}{2}$, so after cancelling either $n+k$ or $n-k$ we can write the left-hand side as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2n}{2}\left(\binom{2n-1}{n-k}-\binom{2n-1}{n-k-1}\right) = n\binom{2n-1}{n-1} = \frac{n}{2}\binom{2n}{n}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. After seeing your very nice and simple answer I agree this might be better suited for the m.SE